# Python:Split dictionary values based on a character

Tags: python, dictionary

This dictionary has some values with "." in it. I want to split those values.

`d={'Id':200, 'Serv': 'df.WST', Floor: 'first', 'Wing': 'B.Wing'}`

I want it to become : (EDITED)

`d={'Id':200, 'Serv': 'df','WST', Floor: 'first', 'Wing': 'B','Wing'}`

I tried split(".")

```
d.values().split(".")

AttributeError: 'dict_values' object has no attribute 'split'
```

I didn't find any other approach for this..

Comment: I dont think the expected result is a valid dictionary

Comment: Are you looing for a list?

Comment: `d={'Id':[200], 'Serv': ['df','WST'], Floor: ['first'], 'Wing':[ 'B', 'Wing']}` 
Is this what you want?

Comment: The `AttributeError: 'dict_values' object has no attribute 'split'` is coming because the first value is an integer. Please have a look.

Comment: @shaikhafizunnisa this `'df','WST'` is still invalid value, post a valid expected result

Comment: @shaikhafizunnisa Your expected output is still wrong. Please correct it.

Comment: Okay I get it. I can't have multiple values for a key

Comment: @shaikhafizunnisa if you want to hold multiple values. better to keep it as a tuple or list

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split string value of a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19441125/split-string-value-of-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
>>> d={'Id':200, 'Serv': 'df.WST', Floor: 'first', 'Wing': 'B.Wing'}
```

---

**Output:**

```
>>> {k:", v.split('.') if isinstance(v, str) else v for k,v in d.items()}
{'Id': 200, 'Serv': ['df', 'WST'], 'Floor': 'first', 'Wing': ['B', 'Wing']}
```

Comment: I feel its better to keep it as a list rather than a string.    
`{key:value.split('.') if isinstance(value, str) else value for key,value in d.items()}`

Comment: @RohanMohapatra It's completely depends on use case of OP.

Comment: I can't convert it to a list. I need it in one format to later write into CSV file

Comment: @shaikhafizunnisa In my answer, data-type of value is string.

Comment: @shaikmoeed It just replaces . with , That is not what I need. I need to separate them like: 'df', 'WST which I now feel is not possible.

Comment: @shaikhafizunnisa It's better you explain your use case in question that why you need `'df', 'WST'`. so that we can suggest, How it is achievable through python.

Comment: @shaikmoeed Because I have a dictionary which is generated from some code in this form. I'm unable to parse the df.WST kind of  values into separate words that is why I was trying to look for another alternative.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196041/discussion-between-shaik-moeed-and-hah).

Answer (score 2):

Since dictionary's values can only have a **list/dict for multiple objects** you can have a list there or join it with some character:

```
output :
{'Id': 200, 'Serv': ['df', 'WST'], 'Floor': 'first', 'Wing': ['B', 'Wing']}

Code:
for k,v in d.items():
    if isinstance(v,str)==True and v.find(".")!=-1:
        d[k]=v.split(".")
        #d[k]=",".join(v.split(".")) or join it as string using some character
```